# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected to be called on the main thread but was RxCachedThreadScheduler in Android

Tags: android, exception, reactivex

I am getting below exception in my android app.

```
 Non-fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected to be called on the main thread but was RxCachedThreadScheduler-20
   at com.jakewharton.rxbinding2.internal.Preconditions.checkMainThread(Preconditions.java:35)
   at com.jakewharton.rxbinding2.view.ViewClickObservable.subscribeActual(ViewClickObservable.java:20)
   at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:12197)
   at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableThrottleFirstTimed.subscribeActual(ObservableThrottleFirstTimed.java:41)
   at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:12197)
   at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableObserveOn.subscribeActual(ObservableObserveOn.java:45)
   at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:12197)
   at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:12183)
   at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:12111)
   at com.test.myapp.helper.MyHelperKt.setThrottledOnClickListener(MyHelper.kt:34)
   at com.test.myapp.helper.MyHelperKt.setThrottledOnClickListener$default(MyHelper.kt:22)
   at com.test.myapp.ui.view.CustomDialog.showGenericErrorModal(CustomDialog.kt:1059)
   at com.test.myapp.MyApplication.onUnavailable(MyApplication.kt:156)
   at com.test.myapp.di.NetworkingModule$CreateUnavailableServiceErrorInterceptor.intercept(NetworkingModule.kt:316)
   at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:112)
   at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:87)
   at com.test.myapp.di.NetworkingModule$CreateAuthInterceptor.intercept(NetworkingModule.kt:351)
   at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:112)
   at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:87)
   at com.test.myapp.di.NetworkingModule$CreateGemaltoErrorInterceptor.intercept(NetworkingModule.kt:269)
   at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:112)
   at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:87)
   at com.test.myapp.di.NetworkingModule$CreateTokenExpirationInterceptor.intercept(NetworkingModule.kt:258)
   at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:112)
   at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:87)
   at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.kt:184)
   at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.kt:66)
   at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.execute(OkHttpCall.java:186)
   at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.CallExecuteObservable.subscribeActual(CallExecuteObservable.java:45)
   at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:12197)
   at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.BodyObservable.subscribeActual(BodyObservable.java:34)
   at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:12197)
   at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableSubscribeOn$SubscribeTask.run(ObservableSubscribeOn.java:96)
   at io.reactivex.Scheduler$DisposeTask.run(Scheduler.java:578)
   at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.run(ScheduledRunnable.java:66)
   at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.call(ScheduledRunnable.java:57)
   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
   at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
```

Given below is the code snippet which causes the exception. I am unable to understand why this issue is happening even though the observeOn is passed as main thread. Please help.

```
    @JvmOverloads
    fun View.setThrottledOnClickListener(throttleTime: Long = Constants.DEFAULT_DEBOUNCE, view: (View) -> Unit): Disposable {
    return RxView.clicks(this).throttleFirst(throttleTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe({ view(this) }, {
       
        it.printStackTrace()
    })
}
```

**EDIT** : This happens when a api callback happens and a custom dialog being shown. Here while setting Custom dialog, to set the button click in that this method is used.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem and solution too. This was getting called in worker thread instead of main thread. When I changed it to main thread it worked.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using subscribeOn()? I can't comment so answered here.

Comment: I tried like this return RxView.clicks(this).throttleFirst(throttleTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).
    observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe({ view(this) }, {
       it.printStackTrace()
    })
But I am unable to reproduce this issue. This crash log I got from production firebase crashlog. So I am not sure whether that will fix the issue or will cause some other issues. As I am new to Rx I wanted someone's help to confirm this.

Comment: I don't think `setThrottledOnClickListener` is causing that exception. Can you please update your answer with API callback as well as dialog related code?

Comment: added complete log in question